# Winforms if a Textbox value exists in DataGridView

Tags: c#, forms, datagridview

How do i ask if a value from a Textbox exists in a DataGridView ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but try this

```
 Dim isFound As Boolean = False  

      For Each row As GridViewRow  In DataGridView1.Rows
           for i As Integer = 0 to DataGridView1.Columns.Count -1
         If row.Cells[i].Text = TextBox1.text  Then
            isFound = True
            exit for
         End If
           Next
        Next
 If (isFound) Then
      MessageBox.Show("Data Exists!")
 Else
       MessageBox.Show("Data Not Exists!")
 EndIf
```

Comment: what is "SearchColumn"?

Comment: update with other code , sorry . Wrong paste

Comment: Any update on this question , have you tryed the new answer